# Oracle Grouping Not Capturing All Rows

Tags: sql

I have the following grouping query and it seems to be leaving out rows...

```
SELECT asscfirstname, assclastname, addeddate, COUNT(*) 
FROM CLUD.masterassc
GROUP BY asscfirstname, assclastname, addeddate
having count (*) >1
order by count(*) desc;
```

This is my data:

```
asscfirstname | assclastname | addeddate
-------------   ------------   ----------
john            doe1           1/1/00
john            doe1           1/1/00
john            doe2           2/1/00
john            doe2           2/1/00
john            doe2           2/5/00
```

The query results only show john doe1.  How do I get it to also include the john doe2 where the addeddate is 2/1/00 since there are two of those?

Comment: Presumably, the strings that look like they are the same are not really the same.  Or perhaps `addeddate` has a time component.

Comment: A `date` in Oracle is actually a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure you have nt hidden space  try using trim()

```
SELECT trim(asscfirstname), trim(assclastname), trim(addeddate), COUNT(*) 
FROM CLUD.masterassc
GROUP BY trim(asscfirstname), trim(assclastname), trim(addeddate)
having count (*) >1
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

A date in Oracle is actually a timestamp, but your default format doesn't show the time portion. Set the time to 00:00:00 before grouping:

```
SELECT asscfirstname, assclastname, trunc(addeddate), COUNT(*) 
FROM CLUD.masterassc
GROUP BY asscfirstname, assclastname, trunc(addeddate)
having count (*) >1
order by count(*) desc;
```